# SVG text element with whitespace not preserved in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, whitespace

I want to preserve the white space in a single SVG < text> element.

This works fine with **xml:space="preserve"** attribute in the text element in all but IE browser.

```
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="red" xml:space="preserve">I     love     SVG!</text>
```

Here is the jsfiddle, try to open this fiddle in Chrome/Firefox and in latest IE, notice that whitespace in the text element text is not preserved in IE.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chetanbh/q4gL7ha4/)

Any workaround so that this works in IE as well?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I guess you could replace each space by `&#160;` (that's the unicode [non-breaking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm) character).

In javascript it would be written as \u00A0 though.

Comment: But creating text elements with whitespace via API is not working http://jsfiddle.net/chetanbh/t4ys4j1x/ with unicode character.

Comment: It's written differently in javascript. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This is a non-ideal answer (comeone IE get your act together) - because now a document text search may not match the content since the character being searched for is no longer a space (ASCII 32) but non breaking space. :(

Comment: Maybe search engines can/do compensate for this?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using d3 this works well:

```
.attr("style","white-space:pre")
```